# Counter that loops through 6 values and then resets

Tags: verilog, counter, clock

This is a counter that loops through
only 6 values over and over again (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, ...).  The counter should include a “reset”
signal that will cause the counter value to reset to 0 when reset goes high (asynchronous reset),
and the counter value should increment on the rising edge of clock.

Here is the code I have. But, how would I make it reset once it reaches the number 5?

```
always @(posedge CLOCK_50 or negedge reset_n) begin
           if (!reset_n)
               count <= 0;
           else if (enable)
               count <= count + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use

```
always @(posedge CLOCK_50 or negedge reset_n) begin
    if (!reset_n)
        count <= 0;
    else if (enable)
        count <= (count == 5)? 'd0 : count + 1;
end
```

or split comb and seq

```
assign count_next = (count == 5)? 0 : count + 1;
always @(posedge CLOCK_50 or negedge reset_n) begin
    if (!reset_n)
        count <= 0;
    else if (enable)
        count <= count_next;
end
```

Comment: When implementing this my count reads as "(0, x, 0, x ....)"

Comment: trace signal or post your waveform

Answer (score 0):

Use another `if/else` to check if `count` is 5, then set it to 0:

```
reg [2:0] count;

always @(posedge CLOCK_50 or negedge reset_n) begin
    if (!reset_n) begin
        count <= 0;
    end else if (enable) begin
        if (count == 5) begin
            count <= 0;
        end else begin
            count <= count + 1;
        end
    end
end
```